# Spring-Boot disable load-on startup rabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

Why RabbitMQ is triggered or running while building the spring-boot jar.While running the Application.java or pom.xml.

i am able to see the following loggers

```
2016-07-01 16:40:04.334  INFO 7004 --- [           main] com.rabbit.App                                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-01 16:40:04.391  INFO 7004 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing    org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1da51a35: startup date [Fri Jul 01 16:40:04 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-01 16:40:05.331  INFO 7004 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'rabbitListenerContainerFactory' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=rabbitMqConfiguration; factoryMethodName=rabbitListenerContainerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/rabbit/messaging/configuration/RabbitMqConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=taskConsumerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=rabbitListenerContainerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/rabbit/messaging/configuration/TaskConsumerConfiguration.class]]
2016-07-01 16:40:05.334  INFO 7004 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'connectionFactory' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=rabbitMqConfiguration; factoryMethodName=connectionFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/rabbit/messaging/configuration/RabbitMqConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=taskConsumerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=connectionFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/rabbit/messaging/configuration/TaskConsumerConfiguration.class]]
2016-07-01 16:40:05.334  INFO 7004 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jsonMessageConverter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=rabbitMqConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jsonMessageConverter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/rabbit/messaging/configuration/RabbitMqConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=taskConsumerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jsonMessageConverter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/rabbit/messaging/configuration/TaskConsumerConfiguration.class]]
2016-07-01 16:40:05.868  INFO 7004 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad9295b0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-01 16:40:06.657  INFO 7004 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
```

Is there any option to disable this?

While building the jar during test phase it throws following exception.

```
LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default  [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@76dc36e5]
2016-06-30 15:10:32.989  WARN 21614 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at     org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:67)
at
```

Comment: This is just bean declaration stuff - exactly what problem do you have?

Comment: RabbitMQ host properties are defined in the application.properties while we build the application we will pass those properties dynamically via using build script. while building the jar during the test phase it throws the below exception.

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: @Gary Russell while building the jar Spring-boot tried to establish the RabbitMQ connection.Is there anyway to do it via lazy loading?I mean on-demand not on start-up?Also i tried with following annotation @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=RabbitAutoConfiguration.class) but no luck.atleast we should lazy load SimpleMessageListenerContainer.Any possibilities of lazy loading RabbitMQ connection or SimpleMessageListenerContainer?

Answer (score 0):

You get the log entry 'Overriding bean definition..' when you define a bean with that name more than once.

This leads to the question, which of the, at least two, beans do you use and how are they configured?

Set breakpoint(s) on the constructor(s) of the rabbitListenerContainerFactory bean and see which instances you are creating.

Looking up the stack trace may give you information about why this bean is created, so you can remove the duplicate from your spring configuration.

You can also add breakpoints, where the rabbit connection properties are set.

"connect timed out" also appears, when the given ip is wrong.

Anyway I would not recommend to set the properties in the build script, instead point to the property files on the command line, when you start the application. That allows you to use your build in different environments.

See [howto-properties-and-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)

**Why it is throwing while building the jar?**
You wrote you are setting the properties with a script during build.

This means that the tests are using those properties and now the tests are failing, may be because the rabbit mq server is not reachable with the provided properties or is not up.

As long as you are overriding beans, you do not really know which instance you use, so you dont really know which properties you use.
Try to log it out, than I am sure you will see....

Comment: thank you for your reply. I do not want few beans automatically provided by spring-rabbit.ex) connectionFactory,ListernerContainerFactory.So i manually configured those beans based on my requirements.So the info message is a valid one but why it is throwing while building the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "lazy load" beans that implement `SmartLifecycle` (such as the listener container) because the context has to load the bean to call `isAutoStartup()` to see whether or not the bean should be started.

If the context is being loaded while "building the jar", you must have test cases that are using the beans. You can set `autoStartup` to `false` - but your tests will probably fail then.

You can skip running the tests with `-DskipTests=true` (maven) or `-x test` (gradle).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my tests. I don't use rabbit and because the timeouts occur the tests duration increases.

As a simple workaround, you can disable the configuration of queues, exchanges etc. during tests using spring profiles.

Example:

Having the configuration that is disabled if the spring profile "no_rabbit" is present.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!no_rabbit")
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("NAMW").withArgument("x-message-ttl", 3600).build();
    }

    // more definitions of bean, exchanges etc.

}
```

Then, in the test simply add the profile "no_rabbit".

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({ "no_rabbit" })
public class TestClass {
     ...
}
```

The drawbacks of this approach is that you have to add the profile in every single test that don't uses rabbit. But for my case it's ok until I have a better solution.